# Rendering plain text through PHP

Tags: php, text, header, robots.txt, plaintext

For some reason, I want to serve my robots.txt via a PHP script. I have setup apache so that the robots.txt file request (infact all file requests) come to a single PHP script.

The code I am using to render robots.txt is:

```
echo "User-agent: wget\n";
echo "Disallow: /\n";
```

However, it is not processing the newlines.  How to server robots.txt correctly, so search engines (or any client) see it properly? Do I have to send some special headers for txt files?

### EDIT 1:

Now I have the following code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "User-agent: wget\n";
echo "Disallow: /\n";
```

which still does not display newlines (see http://sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt ).

### EDIT 2:

Some people mentioned its just fine and not displayed in browser. Was just curious how does this one display correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt

### EDIT 3:

I downloaded both mine and wikipedia's through wget, and see this:

```
$ file en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt
en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt: UTF-8 Unicode English text

$ file sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt
sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt: ASCII text
```

### FINAL SUMMARY:

Main issue was I was not setting the header. However, there is another internal bug, which is making the Content-Type as html. (this is because my request is actually served through an internal proxy but thats another issue).

**Some comments that browsers don't display newline were only half-correct** -> modern browsers correctly display newline if content-type is text/plain. I am selecting the answer that closely matched the real problem and was void of the above slightly misleading misconception :). Thanks everyone for the help and your time!

thanks

JP

Comment: Your content-type is still showing up as "text/html".

Comment: There is either more to your code, or your server is setup to not allow calls to `header` and/or is misconfigured.

Comment: Yes, there is more to my code. Let me try to recreate simplest possible file/scenario and post here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you forgot to set the Content Type of your output to `text/plain`:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Your output is probably being sent as HTML, where a newline is truncated into a space, and to actually display a newline, you would need the `<br />` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I set the header type via the line you mentioned. Still no newlines. Its coming like this: http://sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt

Comment: I checked that page, and I'm still receiving the response type as `text/html`

Comment: oh thats so strange. let me debug further.

Comment: There might be a problem in the way you've set up Apache to "serve files through a single PHP script". If you could provide that code, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

1. `header('Content-Type: text/plain')` is correct.
2. You must call this method **before** anything is written to your output, including white space. Check for whitespace before your opening `<?php`.
3. If your `Content-Type` header has been set to `text/plain`, no browser in its right mind would collapse whitespace. That behaviour is exclusive to HTML and similar formats.
4. I'm sure you have your reasons, but as a rule, serving static content through PHP uses unnecessary server resources. Every hit to PHP is typically a new process spawn and a few megs of memory. You can use apache config directives to point to different robots files based on headers like `User-Agent` - I'd be looking into that.
5. It's likely that search engines ignore the `Content-Type` header, so this shouldn't be an issue anyway.

Hope this helps.

-n

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/plain"); ?>
User-agent: wget
Disallow: /
```

BTW, the newlines are there just fine. They're just **not displayed in a browser**. Browsers collapse all whitespace, including newlines, to a single space.

```
deceze$ curl http://sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt
User-agent: wget
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thanks. How come wikipedia's robots.txt displays correctly in browser? See en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

i was having a similar issue and either "\n" nor PHP_EOL worked. I finally used:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="plaintext.txt"');
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "some data";
echo chr(13).chr(10);
```

The echo of BOTH characters did the trick.
Hope it helps someone.

Bye
anankin

Answer (score 0):

You must set the content type of the document you are serving. In the case of a .txt text file:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

The IANA has information about [some of the more popular MIME (content) types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using echo, then use `<br>` for new lines. the printf function is what uses \n.

In your case, use printf because you are not using HTML. I believe this is the proper way to do this, along with setting the MIME type to text.

Comment: Sorry, that's utter nonsense. `\n` within double quoted strings is always a newline, it has nothing to do with `echo` or `printf`. `<br>` is only useful in the context of HTML.

Comment: `print` is a synonym for `echo`. `printf` is a wrapper around `print` that will substitute different variable into a format string. How you print the content is irrelevant to how it is displayed.